# Get Last <a> tag in element with javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Consider the following html

```
<p id="PgLnks">
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<P></P>
<P></P>
</p>
```

How can I get the latest  tag from the

tag that Id is PgLnks?

i tried this but not worked

```
document.getElementsById('PgLnks').querySelectorAll('a:last-child').outerHTML;
```

Comment: `last-child` only works if the `a` is the last child. Maybe you meant `last-of-type`?

Comment: `:last-of-type`, not `:last-child`.

Comment: That's an invalid HTML

Comment: As @AlonEitan said, the HTML is invalid. You cannot have paragraphs inside another paragraph

Comment: And `querySelectorAll` does not return a DOM element! Read the documentation please

Comment: i see a typo here. It should be `getElementById`

Comment: @AlonEitan i know, this is just a test for explaining issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `getElementById` not `getElementsById`
2. Use `index` as `.querySelectorAll('a:last-child')[0]` then `.outerHTML`
3. Also your `HTML` is invalid as `p` element may not contain other block elements. So when you will check `rendered html` you will see total four `p` tags, what happened was when second `p` starts it will auto close existing `p` tag.

Try with `document.getElementById('PgLnks').querySelectorAll('a:last-child')[0].outerHTML`

```js
let lastA = document.getElementById('PgLnks').querySelectorAll('a:last-child')[0].outerHTML;
console.log(lastA)
```

```html
<p id="PgLnks">
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a>sss</a>
  <P></P>
  <P></P>
</p>
```

---

If you can not use `<%= PgLnks.ClientID %>`, you can try [`attribute selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) as `querySelectorAll('[id$=PgLnks]')` instead of `getElementById('PgLnks')`.

- **[attr^=value]** : Represents elements with an attribute name of *attr* whose value is prefixed (preceded) by *value*.
- **[attr$=value]** : Represents elements with an attribute name of *attr* whose value is suffixed (followed) by *value*.
- [attr*=value] : Represents elements with an attribute name of *attr* whose *value* contains at least one occurrence of *value* within the string.

```js
let lastA = document.querySelectorAll('[id$=PgLnks]')[0].querySelectorAll('a:last-child')[0].outerHTML;
console.log(lastA)
```

```html
<p id="ctl13_ctl00_PgLnks" style="color: #0066ff;" align="center">

۶۷۳ رکورد پیدا شد | در زمان ۳۵ میلی ثانیه | نمایش در ۱۲ صفحه 
<br>
&nbsp;
<a href="/Admin.aspx?mod=Reports&amp;Knd=PersReport&amp;do=Se&amp;FID=2&amp;Page=1">
<img src="Images/Icons/PgPrev.gif" border="0" title="صفحه قبل" align="absmiddle">
</a>
<a href="/Admin.aspx?mod=Reports&amp;Knd=PersReport&amp;do=Se&amp;FID=2&amp;Page=1" style="background-color:#ffffef;padding:3px;border:#a0a0a0 solid 1px;"> &nbsp; ۱ &nbsp; </a>
<a href="/Admin.aspx?mod=Reports&amp;Knd=PersReport&amp;do=Se&amp;FID=2&amp;Page=3"><img src="Images/Icons/PgNext.gif" border="0" title="صفحه بعد" align="absmiddle"></a></p>
```

Comment: May you mention that the HTML is invalid?

Comment: thank you but i get null in my html can you check that?  https://ctxt.io/2/AACgRXYtEg

Comment: Because your `id` is `ctl13_ctl00_PgLnks` & not `PgLnks`. You should use `document.getElementById('<%= PgLnks.ClientID %>')`

Comment: @Karan i know that id is different, i tested in online editor and your code work but I run the code through WebView and C # code `webView.ExecuteScriptAsync()`

Comment: @miladghasemi add in your question how are you using the script with webView.ExecuteScriptAsync(), and also the result you are getting